# Bootstrap causing problems with CSS column property

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and have set the content to display in 2 columns using CSS column property. I know this could be done with Bootstrap, but in this case, it would be better to use CSS columns.

BUT

At least in IOS (Chrome or Safari) the content is not visible at all. If I comment the Bootstrap tags, the content is visible and the CSS columns work fine.

Any ideas?

EDIT (added examples, thanks to Christina ;) )

In this document everything works fine in desktop browsers but if you check it with IOS Chrome or Safari, the text in the CSS columns are not visible.
http://aatosmedia.fi/tmp/column.html

In this second document I commented the Bootstrap 3 CSS -file and now the columns are visible also in IOS.
http://aatosmedia.fi/tmp/column2.html

Comment: Could you include the relevant parts of your CSS to make it easier for people to understand and answer your question?

Comment: Edited the orginal questions (added examples).

Comment: Check your console error log:
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused about `min-height: 1px;` property to `.sisalto` css class. Your div it's visible on both pages but on `column.html` their height it's equals to 1px. Fix it adding some height to your `div`.

Comment: Thanks! That was is. I added min-height: 0; to .sisalto div.